# Changeing Display cache path permanently in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap, cache

I'm looking for a way to change the Cache path of ArcMap permanently.

So from - 
   C:\Users\$username$\AppData\Local\ESRI\Local Caches

To a seperate drive - 
    E:\Users\$username$\ESRI\Local Caches

I'd imagine a registry entry would control this - I haven't been able to find one.

I'd be happy to run a Python script on startup of ArcMap to change this in a automated way - haven't been able to find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 1):

[@KirkKuykendall gave a good suggestion](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/307589/arcmap-10-x-change-display-cache-path-permanently#comment497944_307589) of:

> Have you considered launching arcmap from a bat file that sets the
>   LocalAppData variable before running arcmap.exe?
>   http://environmentvariables.org/LocalAppData 
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/3036367/125400

but I've found that this can be done from the registry as well.

To quote [the ESRI technical documentation](https://support.esri.com/en/Technical-Article/000011373):

> The Cache Path can be changed by setting a new string value “Cache Path” at HKCU\Software\ESRI\Desktop10.x\Settings. If the settings key does not exist, it can be added. This key and string value can be created or viewed by opening ArcMap and navigating to Customize > ArcMap Options > Display Cache.